# ORM one model - multiply tables

Tags: ruby, activerecord, orm, datamapper

Have a database with multiple tables. All tables have the same structure. I am writing a small web application to work with this database on Ruby / Sinatra. I want to simplify the work with tables using ORM - Active Record or DataMapper (preferred). The manuals for the use of a single model for multiple tables offer something like:

```
class Table
   include DataMapper::Resource
   property id, Serial
   property item, String
end

class TableA < Table
   self.table_name = 'table_a'
end

class TableB < Table
   self.table_name = 'table_b'
end
```

How this can be done for several dozen tables without copypaste?

If possible, the decision should be the possibility to add / remove the table without changing the code / settings and restart the application.

Something like:

```
# Model declaration

DataMapper.finalize

itemA = Table.new (use_table: 'table_a')
itemB = Table.new (use_table: 'table_b')
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981724/multiple-database-tables-within-one-ar-model-in-rails-3

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to achive this is using eval.

```
class Table
   include DataMapper::Resource
   property id, Serial
   property item, String
end

table_names = {'TableA' => 'table_a', 'TableB' => 'table_b'}

table_names.each do |klass_name, table_name|
eval <<DYNAMIC
  class #{klass_name} < Table
    self.table_name = '#{table_name}'
  end
DYNAMIC
end
```

Comment: As a solution is possible, but not quite what is needed. Supplemented the question.

Comment: It looks like you want to use a factory pattern. You can add a method in `Table` that will accept the `table_name` and return a subclass of `Table`. You can implement this method by adding a cache of all subclasses in `Table` indexed by their names. If you do not find the current name in the lookup you generate a new subclass and add it to the index.

Comment: I find solution in Active Record. This is code just work:

`class Test < ActiveRecord::Base`
`end`

`Test.table_name = "tests_a"`
`itema = Test.new`
`itema.item = "aaa"`
`itema.save`
 
`Test.table_name = "tests_b"`
`itemb = Test.new`
`itemb.item = "bbb"`
`itemb.save`